# Single-Linked List add(int index, T element) Method

Tags: java, list

I've been working on this project that implements a single-linked list. I've been trying to write the add(int index, T element) method. I have a test class that tests the methods, but each time I test my SLL, any error seems to come back to my add method not running correctly.

I've spent hours working on it, coded different variations, and have drawn out a visualization of the list and how the add method should be working in order to try and get it working. Keeps throwing errors.

One thing I've noticed is at the end of the method, currNode winds up being equivalent to null, which it shouldn't be. I was hoping someone could look over the code below and see what I might be missing. I'd appreciate any guidance or thoughts.

Here is my code so far for the add method:

```
@Override
public void add(int index, T element) {

    // Check if index is out of bounds
    if (index < 0 || index > size()) {
        throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
    }

    // Current node associated with current index
    Node<T> currNode = head;
    // Node before target index node
    Node<T> preTargetNode = null;
    // New node to be added to list
    Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(element);
    if (index == 0) {
        addToFront(element);
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            preTargetNode = currNode;
            currNode = currNode.getNext();
        }

        preTargetNode.setNext(newNode);
        newNode.setNext(currNode);

        size++;
        modCount++;
    }
}
```

Thank you all so much for your time!

Comment: Well, it _looks_ like it ought to work.  Have you tried to isolate the problem by single-stepping through the code with the debugger?  Are you certain the problem is in `add` itself and not `addToFront`?

Comment: _Keeps throwing errors._ What errors? Please include the specific errors in your question.

Comment: @KevinAnderson Yes I am certain it's within add and not addToFront. I have a class that has 2710 tests in it to thoroughly tests all methods of my list. All my other tests specific to addToFront pass. 

Ive used a debugger and it's both shown issues with add, and other methods that use add fail. In essence, all data suggests it's an issue with with add() method itself.

Despite running through with a debugger I can't fully understand the issue. All I know is currNode is null at the end when it shouldn't be. Issue is somewhere with the logic and design of the method.

Comment: @IvoMori The errors being thrown depends. As stated, I have about class that contains 2710 tests for my list. There are a series of tests for each method depending on what chance scenarios occur in my list. The methods depend on add(), and so the error messages I get chance depending on how add() was changed. I can't really provide a specific error message.

Answer (score 0):

Try to loop like this in else-condition

```
while (currNode != null && index-- > 0) {
    preTargetNode = currNode;
    currNode = currNode.getNext();
}

preTargetNode.setNext(newNode);
newNode.setNext(currNode);

size++;
modCount++;
```

Comment: I tested it out and finding I'm getting the exact same errors from my test class that I was before. I'm getting errors with my iterator hasNext, and next() methods for certain list change scenarios. What's odd is these errors only occur for a couple specific scenarios and not for all scenarios. The hasNext and next() methods I have pass for other chance scenarios. 

Let me go through things again with a debugger and see if I can come up with some new info. Thank you for your time and input.

Comment: Ok...so what's happening is when a Node and its element are being added to the list, they are being tacked on AFTER the tail (the tail node then points to the newNode, and the newNode points to null). What should happen is if the node is added before the tail then the new node should point to tail and the tail to null. if the element is added at the end of the list then the old tail should point to the new node, the new node should become the tail and then point to null.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the problem....I needed to check if the previous node was the tail, and if it was then update the tail of the list. Also found that one of my remove methods wasn't shifting correctly.

Here is the new code for the add(int index, T element) method:

```
@Override
    public void add(int index, T element) {

        // Check if index is out of bounds
        if (index < 0 || index > size()) {
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException();
        }

        // Current node associated with current index
        Node<T> currNode = head;
        // Node before target index node
        Node<T> preTargetNode = null;
        // New node to be added to list
        Node<T> newNode = new Node<T>(element);
        if (index == 0) {
            addToFront(element);
        } else {

            for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
                preTargetNode = currNode;
                currNode = currNode.getNext();
            }

            preTargetNode.setNext(newNode);
            newNode.setNext(currNode);

            if (preTargetNode == tail) {
                tail = newNode;
                tail.setNext(null);
            }

            // Increment list size
            size++;

            // Increment list mod count
            modCount++;
        }
    }
```